# Selenium and SSO

Tags: selenium, junit, single-sign-on

I need to run my Selenium Webdriver JUnit tests separately, but also all at once. I've been looking for a solution for something that basically cuts down to one single issue: I'm testing an application which uses SSO.

That means, I have to manually sign in when I run a test. This is on the other hand even desired, because you don't want to store critical passwords in any files. This is not even harmfull when you run a single test. But when you're in need to run them all, and you have about 100 tests, you would have to sign in 100 times. No way Jose!

I have found out that one possible solution could be Java proxy server. I find codes that show how to create and handle one, but not the SSO part in it. Can anyone help me? Or will the password be stored somewhere either ways?

Answer (score 2):

You need to find out more about your SSO implementation. I suggest using your browser's developer tools our a debugging proxy such as Fiddler or Charles to capture the HTTP traffic between your browser and the servers during SSO authentication, then implementing these requests in a Java web client. SSO authentication often results in setting a cookie. If you capture this cookie after the authentication phase, then you can reuse this cookie in every Selenium test.

The authentication will require credentials, which you could put into a properties file. You could exclude this properties file from source control, and ask all developers to use their own credentials when running tests.